# apache derby composite function error problem

Tags: sql, derby

So I'm working on a java app which has apache derby embedded. I'm having undesired results with my queries on the database tables.
there is a table 
lottotable(date,city,int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5)
there is a table extdates(id, date) which contains distinct dates referenced by lottotable.

the query i'm doing which is giving me problems needs to get a lottotable block when given a date and a blocksize with the date given being the last date in the block and the rows of the block being equal to block size.

why is this query not being successful?

```
" SELECT l.* from lottotable as l  where l.city='"+city+"' and l.date >=  "
                        + "( select e.date from extdates as e where e.id =  select sum( (select e1.id from extdates as e1 where e1.date=( cast('"+date+"'as date) )- cast('"+blockSize+"' as integer )" +
                                                                                        ")"+
                        ")"
                        +  "and l.date < cast('"+date+"' as date) ) order by date )"
```

Comment: Whats the error you are facing?

Comment: in database existence test java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "select" at line 1, column 121.
Derby shut down normally

Comment: " SELECT l.* from lottotable as l  where l.city='"+city+"' and l.date >=  "
                        + "( select e.date from extdates as e where e.id =  select sum( (select e1.id from extdates as e1 where e1.date=( cast('"+date+"'as date) )- cast('"+blockSize+"' as integer )" +
                                                                                        ")"+
                      ")"
                        +  "and l.date < cast('"+date+"' as date) ) order by date "

Comment: I can see extra ) after order by data and I removed it. Can You try?

Comment: Still getting an error, soo strange..
in database existence test java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "select" at line 1, column 118.
Derby shut down normally

Comment: can you change 1.* into 1.city and give it a short.

Comment: my goodness this thing is getting me crazy, still giving me the error encountered I changed the statement to this and I get the same error ...
{

Comment: " SELECT l.city from lottotable as l where l.city='"+city+"' and l.date >= "
        + "( select e.date from extdates as e where e.id = sum( (select e1.id from extdates as e1 where e1.date=( cast('"+date+"'as date) )" +
        "               - cast('"+blockSize+"' as integer )" +
                      ")"+
        ")"
         + "and l.date < cast('"+date+"' as date) " +
          " order by date "

Comment: share your table structure and sample data for testing purpose.